# Design concept (pattern?) for method call in c#?

Tags: c#

I would like to create a structure where I call a method and this method parameter should be only available only from an instanced class.

What I exactly mean..., I have a class which contains functions like:

```
public class Functions
{
        public Request GetId(int item)
        {
            //return instanced request
        }

        public Request SetId(int item)
        {
            //return instanced request
        }
}
```

I have an invoker class, which has a method, called Invoke(Request request).

I would like to use Functions class as the parameter of this method, but accepted parameters can only be come from this class.

Actually I do this to create an instance from the functions class inside the class of the Invoke method and looks like this:

```
Functions Requests = new Functions();
```

...so when I would like to call the Invoke method, it looks like this:

```
Invoke(Requests.GetId(1));
```

But is there any way to solve, that I can only Invoke Requests from the instanced class, like:

```
Invoke(GetId(1));
```

Maybe I think on a wrong way but hopefully, it's clear what I would like to reach. (Seperate Functions from the Invoker class but keep the relation between them).

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should read up on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) especially the Single Responsibility Pattern. When you create classes in C# you should name them in a way that allows you to recognise immediately what they're doing. So calling a class `Functions` is a bad name because it is a generic name. Calling it something like `RequestModifiers` is getting closer, still not good but I don't know what the class is meant to do. And you should invoke methods from other methods hiding their intention

Answer (score 0):

Why not to make class and methods `static`

```
public static class Functions
{
        public static Request GetId(int item)
        {
            //return instanced request
        }

        public static  Request SetId(int item)
        {
            //return instanced request
        }
}
```

and then

`using static Functions;`

you will be able to use this syntex then:

`Invoke(GetId(1));`

**But** this is not good practice.

Comment: Because by introducing statics you make your code harder to test and maintain....

Comment: @CallumLinington the question is how to make this `Invoke(GetId(1));` valid. This issue is arleady something strange where "test and maintaining" is not the problem.

Comment: You said "Why not make class and methods `static`" opening you question up for debate. I answered why you wouldn't do this. You aren't helping someone when you give them bad advice.

Comment: @CallumLinington I agree that he should not do that. But also there is not other way to call given method in this particular way in given example.